# formatting error on local wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

I had to install a backup (mysql dump & apache document-root tgz) of a wordpress website on my local linux laptop and after setting it all up I notized strange formatting erros on my local installation ... text content like this:

```
[/span6] [/row] [row] [span4] [hero_unit title="The Best Business Ideas & Solutions" 
text="Masagni dolores eoquie voluptatequnt. Niquerro quisquam estqui dolorem sumquia 
dolor sitamet conetase adipisci unumquam eius. Basmodi temporaunt, ut laboreas dolore 
magnam aliquam." btn_text="read more" btn_link="http://test.localhost/et-sit-amet-euismod-
in-auctor-ut-ligula-aterse/etiam-dictum-egestas/" btn_style="primary" btn_size="normal" 
target="_self"] [/span4] [span1] [spacer] [/span1] [span7] [title_box title="Company 
Profile"] [row_in] [span3]
```

I'm quite new to wordpress but guess there must something missing (apache plugin?) on my local installation but I have no clue ... anyone of you?

Thanks,
max

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a plugin is missing (a WordPress plugin, not an apache one). Is it [grid-shortcodes](http://www.pagelines.com/shop/plugins/grid-shortcodes/)?

If it is, simply download the plugin, unzip it to the `wp-content/plugins` directory and active the plugin from the WordPress admin.

Comment: Allright, but shouldn't I have backuped all included plugins if I zipped the entire document-root directory where wordpress was installed before?

Comment: Possibly. Have all the plugins been activated in the admin?

Comment: Yes, they are all activated!